# How to accomplish File I/O in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Filewrite
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter your name:: ");
      String Name = in.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter your marks in subject 1:: ");
      int marks1 = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter your marks in subject 2:: ");
      int marks2 = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter your marks in subject 2:: ");
      int marks3 = in.nextInt();
      File f = new File("testdata.txt");
      OutputStream cout = new FileOutputStream(f);    //Error is here
      System.out.println("Name    " + Name);
      System.out.println("Marks1  " + marks1);
      System.out.println("Marks2  " + marks2);
      System.out.println("Marks3  " + marks3);
   }
}
```

What's wrong with the program? Unreported exception, File not found exception.
I thought that if the file is not present it creates a new file like C++. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It's likely that the FileNotFoundException is dealing with the possibility that the file cannot be created. As the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File)) state *"if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason"*

Comment: Then how to crate a file and use it in the program. Usually in C++ the file is automatically created.

Comment: The FileOutputStream should create the if the above mentioned conditions are not met...

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @Kayaman I am using Netbeans and it says: Unreported exception FilenotFoundException, must be caught or declared to be thrown.

Comment: That's a compilation error I think. You need to throw the IOException in the main method, or use a try catch block around the file operations.

Comment: I'm assuming that you know about [try blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't but I am trying. Could you also share the corrected version of the code.

Comment: Guys don't answer about the try-catch or throws method. As I tried both of them the program is executable but it does not write to the file. Also the program runs fine without these exceptions and shows the output with an error. I want the details written to the file.

Comment: There is probably no such file, you need to create one. Also, you probably need to catch such exceptions using a try-catch block.

Comment: @Hunter Your program doesn't run at all. It's not a legal Java program. Take the advice you're given here, overcome your aversion, put in the try-catch blocks, and try again. If you're just going to argue about it, I don't see the point of posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the obvious things...

[`FileOutputStream(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29)

> **Throws:**
>  `FileNotFoundException` - if the
>   file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not
>   exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

What this means you need to trap exceptions you can handle or re-throw those you don't want to/can't.

In this case, you should try and catch the exception and, at the very least, display the details.

Take a close look at [The `try` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) (and other tuortials listed on the subject)

You should also take a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Now, there's nothing wrong with using the `FileOutputStream`, but it is kind of low-level for simply writing text, instead, the following example uses a `BufferedWriter` which writes to a `FileWriter`, the main reason for using this is because it has two simple methods that makes life easier, the first is `write(String)` and the other is `newLine`

```
public class Filewrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name:: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your marks in subject 1:: ");
        int marks1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your marks in subject 2:: ");
        int marks2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter your marks in subject 2:: ");
        int marks3 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Name    " + name);
        System.out.println("Marks1  " + marks1);
        System.out.println("Marks2  " + marks2);
        System.out.println("Marks3  " + marks3);
        File f = new File("testdata.txt");

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))) {
            bw.write("name=" + name);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Marks1=" + marks2);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Marks2=" + marks2);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Marks3=" + marks2);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This examples utilises the `try-with-resource` feature of Java 7+, which automatically closes the writer once the `try-block` exists, it saves on having to implement a `finally` block

Answer (score 2):

You need to either use a try/catch block, or add throws `FileNotFoundException` to the method (and handle it in the calling method).

Basic exception handling, if you're not familiar with it, now's the time to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Just include  OutputStream cout = new FileOutputStream(f); inside try-catch or add throws keyword to the methode.

```
 try { OutputStream cout = new FileOutputStream(f);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

To write content to file you need to use cout.write(*your content here*)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If a file is not found, it is not created automatically.
You have to instruct to create the file.

**Example**:

```
File f = new File( "testdata.txt" );

// create new file if does not exists
f.createNewFile(); // if exists, ignores

OutputStream cout = new FileOutputStream( f );

// now write the data into the file
cout.write( "Name    " + Name + "\n" );
cout.write( "Marks1  " + marks1 + "\n" );
cout.write( "Marks2  " + marks2 + "\n" );
cout.write( "Marks3  " + marks3 + "\n" );
```

You, however, have to handle Exceptions.